# Read a dtoverlay controlled device via Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, sensors

How to read a dtoverlay controlled device, i.e. sensor via pyhon3?

I can read the device via a simple cat, for example...

```
# cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0077/iio\:device0/in_temp_input
27130
```

So I know the basic setup and such is good, sensor is at address 0x77, it is a BME280 sensor, etc.

I can also read the sensor via the various python3 libraries for such sensors, say the python library from Adafruit.

But I want to use the dtoverlay method of sensor control, i.e. read, and read the sensor from python3.  This seemed obvious and straight forward, but apparently not, tried the following code and got the following error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
#

import os

#

theSensor=os.open('/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0077/iio\:device0/in_temp_input', os.O_RDONLY)
os.lseek(theSensor, 0, os.SEEK_SET)
print(os.read(theSensor, 2))
theSensor.close()
```

And the error...

```
# python3 BME280-OverLay.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/BME280-OverLay.py", line 17, in <module>
    theSensor=os.open('/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0077/iio\:device0/in_temp_input', os.O_RDONLY)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0077/iio\\:device0/in_temp_input'
```

Is there some trick to reading this specific device path via python3?  The simple cat works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initial `cat` command, you noticed that there's a **`\`** inside the URL. That's an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). It might be there because you used autocompletion with the Tab key ; in this case `bash` adds it automatically, even though in fact `cat` doesn't need it, but deals with it.

`python` doesn't (deal with it). You'll have to feed `open()` with the clear path syntax.

By the way you can use a plain `open()` call and the `with` syntax :

```py
with open('/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0077/iio:device0/in_temp_input', 'r') as fd:
    temp = fd.read()
print(temp)
```

This way, the file gets closed before the `print()` call.

PS: the fact that the file you are trying to read is on a virtual filesystem would have no impact.

Comment: I accepted your answer but I noticed something odd, the path is actually different in your example versus my original path... slash versus back-slash.  The back slash in the reference path at the 'iio:device0' reference.  This is in fact correct if you list the file system.  So I am a bit surprised you changed the path in you example, but realized it is a literal '\:', which explains my original error I believe.

Comment: That backslash is the point of my answer ! I updated it hoping to make it more understandable. BTW the strict path doesn't contain any backslash ; you can see it with the result of ```ls /sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0077/```

Comment: Yup, when I asked the question, initially, I had completely missed that difference, thinking the path was just an odd device path specification.  It was not until I saw your response that I realized it was an escaped literal.  I actually did go back and did an 'ls' just to confirm I had missed it initially.